# how to create a dll of the project

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin.forms

Actually I am working on Xamarin.Forms Project in visual studio 2012.When I build the solution then it gives the following error-

Metadata file "Prject name.dll" could not be found.

How to overcome from this problem.

Comment: Where would you like to use the dll for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close VS.
Delete all bin and obj folders in the project (pcl and platform).
Open VS and project.
Make sure you have all projects are selected on your build configurations.
Clean.
Rebuild.

See if that works.

Also what is the version of forms ? Does it happen if you try one of the templates file-> new project ?